# Simple count down clock not working in notepad

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to add this clock into my code but it does not show on the page, anyone know why? I have tried copying it in notepad but no success.

http://jsfiddle.net/yS4da/2707/

```
<code id="time"></code>
<script>
    var midnight = "0:00:00";
    var now = null;

    setInterval(function () {
        now = moment().format("H:mm:ss");
        if (now === midnight) {
            alert("Hi");
        }
        $("#time").text(now);
    }, 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: jsfiddle provides a complete runnable and valid html site. How look your "html site"?

Answer (score 0):

If you look into the developer console (F12) you will see that "moment ist no defined". The fiddle is using [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) which you need to include. Consider that the project is [considered as legacy](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/).

Comment: hm I have downloaded moment.js, and put a script with its file destination in but still does not seem to work.